# How to render Background image not of power of two

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm new to DirectX, and I am trying to render a Texture that is of dimension 300 x 570 pixels.

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

I am using Windows 8, and feature level 11_0, and I have access to a function that loads textures from *.DDS files.

However, it is my understanding that DDS textures have dimensions that are of a power of two, and my background texture does not, therefore I cannot convert my background image (currently .jpg) to a .dds format.

How might someone render this background texture efficiently?

Comment: Naively, I'd just resize the image to 512x1024 - ensuring I didn't stretch the original image, but rather added blank pixels. I.e, create new image 512x1024 pixels, copy 300x570 image to top left corner. Then, I'd just use scaling factors to apply to the UVs. I.e if the U varied from [0 .. 1] for the 300x570 image, it would now vary from [0 .. 0.5859] (300/512 = ~0.5859). The V was in the range of [0..1], it would now have the range [0 .. 0.55664] This would give you scaling fators of 0.5859 and 0.55664 for U and V respectively. :shurgs:

Comment: DDS Texture Format supports non power of two, only on (very) low feature level you do need power of two (but even on feature 9 it's already fine). So you can safely convert your texture.